App crashing after changing minsdk IN FLUTTER
I am working on this app and it crashes when i run it, All i did was change the minsdk version for firebase and added firebase dependencies and eversince the app is crashing i don't know for what reason i didnot change any package names in Manifestfile or anywhere
here is my console output
Launching lib\main.dart on ONEPLUS A6013 in debug mode...
✓ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk
E/AndroidRuntime(11592): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(11592): Process: com.mujidev.encryptvault, PID: 11592
E/AndroidRuntime(11592): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mujidev.encryptvault/EncryptVault.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "EncryptVault.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~2GuzoqKLPSLIMGWKnGSxAA==/com.mujidev.encryptvault-x9dPC4W8jB86qaKDCgIlfw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~2GuzoqKLPSLIMGWKnGSxAA==/com.mujidev.encryptvault-x9dPC4W8jB86qaKDCgIlfw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~2GuzoqKLPSLIMGWKnGSxAA==/com.mujidev.encryptvault-x9dPC4W8jB86qaKDCgIlfw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(11592):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3532)
E/AndroidRuntime(11592):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3780)
E/AndroidRuntime(11592):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime(11592):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(11592):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(11592):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2251)
E/AndroidRuntime(11592):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(11592):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
E/AndroidRuntime(11592):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8068)
E/AndroidRuntime(11592):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(11592):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
E/AndroidRuntime(11592):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
E/AndroidRuntime(11592): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "EncryptVault.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~2GuzoqKLPSLIMGWKnGSxAA==/com.mujidev.encryptvault-x9dPC4W8jB86qaKDCgIlfw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~2GuzoqKLPSLIMGWKnGSxAA==/com.mujidev.encryptvault-x9dPC4W8jB86qaKDCgIlfw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~2GuzoqKLPSLIMGWKnGSxAA==/com.mujidev.encryptvault-x9dPC4W8jB86qaKDCgIlfw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(11592):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
E/AndroidRuntime(11592):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(11592):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(11592):    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(11592):    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(11592):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1273)
E/AndroidRuntime(11592):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3520)
E/AndroidRuntime(11592):    ... 11 more


i tried adding 'package="com.mujidev.encryptvault' in the Manifest file but the error had not luck
i also tried to change the minsdk from 21 to 23 but still got the same error
here is my manifest file
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <application
        android:label="encryptvault"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>


here is another file MainActivity.kt which i think might have something to do with this error
package com.mujidev.encryptvault

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity()


After changing the minsdk from 21 to 23 i tried to revert the changes to flutter.minsdkversion and yes then the error doesn't show up but i won't be able to implement firebase w/o changing the min sdk
